# Can't get data-* value from html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning to build a e-commerce site using django , while adding add-to-cart functionality
I couldn't pass product ID to js file. And I am new to javascript
cart.js

```
var updateBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (var i=0; i<updateBtn.length; i++){
    updateBtn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:',productId, 'action:',action )

        })

}
```

product.html

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <p><span>$320</span> <i class="item_price">RS.{{product.price}}</i></p>
    <p><a data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="update-cart" >Add to Cart</a></p>
</div>
```

attachment in base.html

```
<script src="{% static 'store/js/cart.js' %}"></script>
```